# Passing several items to IN Clause in Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, procedure

How to pass several items to IN clause in procedure, like EXEC TEST1('A','E') or EXEC TEST1('A','D', 'E')? The number of items is not pre-determined.

With only one item, the procedure TEST1 can be as follow.
And EXEC TEST1('A') or TEST1('E') works with no problem.

```
 CREATE TABLE T1  (  
            C1 VARCHAR2,
            C2 VARCHAR2
     );

    INSERT INTO T1(C1)  VALUES ('A');
    INSERT INTO T1(C1)  VALUES ('B');
    INSERT INTO T1(C1)  VALUES ('C');
    INSERT INTO T1(C1)  VALUES ('D');
    INSERT INTO T1(C1)  VALUES ('E');

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1(p1 IN  VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO T1(C2)
SELECT C1 FROM T1  WHERE C1 IN (p1);
END;
/
```

How should the above code be modified to accept several input items with no pre-determined number of them?
What shoud be modified?

Comment: What Oracle version are you using? I assume it's not extremely old so it should support what I am about to suggest. Do you know about the _table type_ in Oracle? Do you know about _bulk insert_ in Oracle? The procedure parameter can be a PL/SQL collection type, such as a table type.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a custom collection type and make that as the procedure argument. Inside the procedure, use the `TABLE` function to unnest the collection.

Type

```
create or replace type c1tab AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
```

Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1(p1 IN  c1tab)
IS
BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO T1(C2)
    SELECT C1 FROM T1  WHERE 
         C1 IN ( select column_value from  TABLE(p1)
         );
END;
/
```

Execution

```
EXEC  TEST1( c1tab('A','D', 'E'));
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bb592c6cf032b5f8520046009f069288)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to split input string into rows and use it in `IN` clause:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1 (p1 IN VARCHAR2)
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     INSERT INTO t1 (c2)
  5        SELECT c1
  6          FROM t1
  7         WHERE c1 IN (    SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (p1,
  8                                                      '[^,]+',
  9                                                      1,
 10                                                      LEVEL))
 11                            FROM DUAL
 12                      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (p1, ',') + 1);
 13  END;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t1;

C1         C2
---------- ----------
A
B
C
D
E

SQL> EXEC test1('A,D, E');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t1;

C1         C2
---------- ----------
           A
           D
           E
A
B
C
D
E

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```